# About how to create in Oracle Express - SQL. A trigger to update a column

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have a `product` table and a `sales` table. Inside the `product` I have `(product_id, p_desc, qty_stock)` and in the `sales` table I have `(sale_id, producto_id, sale_p_qty)` where `sale_p_qty` is the quantity that a customer buys from a certain product.

The question would be how can I make a trigger to update the `qty_stock` column value in the `product` table (this value would be the stock)? I can not do it. I can do a trigger that decrements, but only one value at a time. The correct one would be to get the `sale_p_qty` of table `sales` and decrement in `qty_stock` but I can not do that. Could you please give me a hand?

My attempt stopped at this (I did not do a procedure, I do not know if you need to in this case):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_stock_ai AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON sale
FOR EACH ROW
declare
    new_stock NUMBER (4);
    --SELECT sale_p_qty INTO new_stock FROM sale
    --SET new_stock = (SELECT sale_p_qty FROM sale);
BEGIN
    SELECT sale_p_qty INTO new_stock FROM sale;
    UPDATE product
    SET qty_stock = qty_stock - new_stock
    WHERE product.product_id =: NEW.product_id;
END;
```

Comment: Don't do it like that. Calculate stock quantity *real-time*. In order to do so, when you "buy" (or produce) something put it into the SALES table with a `+` sign. When you sell something, put it into the SALES table with a `-` sign. Then, when you want to know stock amount, simply `select sum(quantity) from sales where id = some_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two steps:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_stock_ai AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON sale
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE product
        SET qty_stock = (qty_stock - :NEW.sale_p_qty)
        WHERE p.product_id = :NEW.product_id;

    UPDATE product
        SET qty_stock = (qty_stock + :OLD.sale_p_qty)
        WHERE p.product_id = :OLD.product_id;
END;
```

This should work for both inserts and updates, even when `product_id` changes.